# laravel and artisan error cannot add foreign key on migrate

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

I know this has been answered many times as i saw many answers suggestions when i wrote the question, but none of them actually get me the correct answer.

When i try to add new field to the table and use artisan migrate in laravel i get an error

```
General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `pages` add constraint pages_page_status_foreign foreign key (`page_status`) references `page_status` (`status_value`))
```

But i don't understand why do i get an error when before i have done the same thing and with no errors, only answer i could think of is that it's not possible to have two or more foreign keys on same table. Here is my migrate function

```
class CreateStatusTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('page_status', function($table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('status_name');
        $table->integer('status_value')->unsigned();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('page_status');
}
```

}

This is for status table, and now i have to add new field to pages table using this.

```
class AddStatusToPagesTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('pages', function($table) {
        $table->integer('page_status')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('page_status')->references('status_value')->on('page_status');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('pages', function($table) {
        $table->dropForeign('pages_page_status_foreign');
    });
}

}
```

And this is where the error appears, for some reason it does not let me set foreign key on page_status field into pages table.

I am using xampp installation on my localhost and in phpmyadmin i can see that table is set to innodb, actually everything is set to innodb by default. and inside my database in pages table looking at page_status field i have first to set it index than i am able to use relations. why it's not set to index i don't know but i already have on that table id as an index and author as foreign key.

Before this i also added few fields when creating pages table and using this

```
class CreatePagesTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('pages', function($table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('author')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('author')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('pages');
}
```

}

I did not had any problems when using migrate, it worked well and author is set as foreign key.

So why i can't add new foreign key now ?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the fact that a foreign key can't be added if the current records do not meet the condition. If `page_status` is optional make the field nullable:

```
$table->integer('page_status')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

If you don't want to make it nullable and are going to insert valid foreign key values later you can disable foreign key checks temporarily:

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');

Schema::table('pages', function($table) {
    $table->integer('page_status')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('page_status')->references('status_value')->on('page_status');
});

DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
```

Comment: But why it can't meet the condition, it worked before as i showed in example when i added "author" foreign key, adding nullable() doesn't change anything, still i get the error.

Comment: You added the first foreign key when no rows where in the database. Now there probably are some, that's causing the problem. Have you tried the foreign key checks method?

Comment: i did not tried foreign check method, but i made it working by setting field as an index manually, you can see in my answer below.

Comment: Interesting... Anyways, glad you got it worked out :)

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem is, after adding a new field to the table you have to set the index on that field, so there is a one step further on migration for setting the field as index.

I still do not understand why in my first migration when i added "author" field it made it automatically as an index but for this one i got it working by setting index additionally like this:

```
    Schema::table('pages', function($table) {
        $table->integer('status')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->index('status');

        $table->foreign('status')->references('status_value')->on('page_status');
    });
```